# How to pass variable in Load command from IBM Object Storage file to Cloud DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, object-storage

I am using below command to load Object Storage file into DB2 table:NLU_TEMP_2.

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('load from "S3::s3.jp-tok.objectstorage.softlayer.net::
<s3-access-key-id>::<s3-secret-access-key>::nlu-test::practice_nlu.csv"
 OF DEL modified by codepage=1208 coldel0x09 method P (2) WARNINGCOUNT 1000
 MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT into DASH12811.NLU_TEMP_2(nlu)');
```

above command inserts 2nd column from object storage file to  DASH12811.NLU_TEMP_2 in nlu column.

I want to insert request_id from variable as a additional column:request_id in DASH12811.NLU_TEMP_2(request_id,nlu).

I read in some article to use statement concentrator literals to dynamically pass a value. Please let us know if anyone has an idea on how to use it.

Note, i would be using this query in DB2 but not DB2 warehouse. External tables wont work in DB2.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD` does not have any ability to include extra values that are not part of the load file. You can try to do things with columns that are generated by default in Db2 but it is not a good solution.

Really you need to wait until DB2 on Cloud supports external tables

Comment: i read in some article to use statement concentrator literals to dynamically pass a value. do you have any idea on how to do that.

Comment: If that is a new question, ask a new SO question. If it relates to your original question, then the point about LOAD is that you can't add literal values info the data that you are loading. external tables  and `INGEST` can do that, but I don;t thin INGEST has a remote storage option